# How do I call a call method from XAML in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How do I call a call method from XAML in WPF?

Answer (score 6):

The typical way this is handled is by wrapping your method into an [ICommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.aspx), and using the [Commanding infrastructure in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx).

I [blogged about Commanding](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/12/28/better-user-and-developer-experiences-from-windows-forms-to-wpf-with-mvvm-part-5-commands/), showing some of the advantages of this approach, especially when you use something like the RelayCommand implementation in [Josh Smith's MVVM article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx).

Comment: Note that using the commanding infrastructure only executes a method on user interaction. Otherwise read up on xaml triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Except the commands there is another way that allows you to call a method directly from XAML. It is not commonly used but the option is still there.

The method must have one of the two types of signatures

- void Foo()
- void Bar(object sender, EventArgs e)

To make it working, you have to include references and namespaces of the `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions` and `System.Windows.Interactivity` into your project. Easiest way is to install a [nuget.](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SDK.Expression.Blend/) In the example below the namespaces are defined  as `xmlns:i` and  `xmlns:ei`.

```
<Window x:Class="Interactivity.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="Run" IsEnabled="{Binding CanRun}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="VoidParameterlessMethod" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                <ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="EventHandlerLikeMethod" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public void VoidParameterlessMethod() 
        => Console.WriteLine("VoidParameterlessMethod called");

    public void EventHandlerLikeMethod(object o, EventArgs e) 
        => Console.WriteLine("EventHandlerLikeMethod called");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can create RelayCommand inheriting ICommand, and then create property of ICommand and assign relay command to that property and call the method.