# How to call function from XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have the following xaml code:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
        <EventTrigger.Actions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5" Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundBrush" From="0.5">
                    </DoubleAnimation>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger.Actions>
    </EventTrigger>
```

Also, I want to call some function when MouseEnter is raised

```
    void UpdateTimeAfterMouseOver()
    {
        timeAfterLastMouseOver = _timeAfterLastMouseOver_init;
    }
```

how to do it? I imaging it to do via command model, but can't imaging how :)

Comment: yes, it's better to use event hanlder. if you indeed want to call method from xaml. you may find a solution from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3041718/function-call-within-xaml-code

Comment: I assume you are using MVVM. Just because you are using MVVM, you do not have to avoid all code-behind. Code-behind which controls/manipulates the View without reading the Data or writing to it is just fine in your code-behind, so you can use a EventHandler.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a call method from XAML in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186382/how-do-i-call-a-call-method-from-xaml-in-wpf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would simply use [MouseEnter Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter.aspx).

```
<Window MouseEnter="OnMouseEnterHandler"
```

.

```
void OnMouseEnterHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```