# Calling C# Function from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my XAML I have an expander like this

```
<Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Width="Auto" Padding="4">
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding XPath=@Expand}" />
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
    <ListBox Name="itemsList"
    ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=UpgradeAction}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtListItemTemplate}"
    SelectionChanged="listItems_SelectionChanged"
    Style="{StaticResource styleListBoxUpgradeAction}"
    ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleListBoxItemUpgradeAction}">
    </ListBox>
</Expander>
```

Instead of the value of Header to come from @Name I want to have a C# function to take in the @Name from the XAML, do some things, then output a new string which will be used as the Value. So it would look something like this

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="C_Sharp_Function({Binding XPath=@Name})" />
```

I have the function that I need to use but how do I execute this in the XAML?Sorry if this sounds like a stupid question, I'm new to C# and XAML.  Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is some of the things I tried in the Setter to substitute a multi-value converter. I assume it should look something like the answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980039/wpf-ivalueconverter-converting-multiple-values-into-a-single-value).

```
<Setter Property="Header" Value="{{Binding XPath=@Name, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}, {Binding XPath=@Value, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}}" />

 <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding XPath={@Name, @Value}, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" />
```

Comment: Bind to a property on your viewmodel, and in the getter for the property put the code from you function

Comment: I sort of agree with @Milney, why not just use a property on your viewmodel that returns the proper value for Header? why would it need to do a round trip like that?

Comment: But that is what converters do. So add a converter to your binding and do what you need there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I call a call method from XAML in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2186382/how-do-i-call-a-call-method-from-xaml-in-wpf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're describing is a [value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). It looks a little different, but logically it's the same thing.

```
public class NameConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var name = (XmlAttribute)value;

        //  Do anything you like in here. This is just an example. 

        return "something based on " + name.Value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter" />

    <!-- ... -->
```

...

```
<Expander ExpandDirection="Down" Width="Auto" Padding="4">
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding XPath=@Expand}" />
            <Setter 
                Property="Header" 
                Value="{Binding XPath=@Name, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" 
                />
```

If you want to pass in more than one parameter, you can use a [multi-binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx) with a [multi-value converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

I'm not sure why you'd doing all your bindings in the Expander's Style. The following should work equally well. I also included a simpler way to do the `IsExpanded` trigger.

```
public class NameValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var attrName = (XmlAttribute)values[0];
        var attrValue = (XmlAttribute)values[1];

        //  Do stuff here. 

        return attrName.Value + " -> " + attrValue.Value;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}


<Window.Resources>
    <local:NameValueConverter x:Key="NameValueConverter" />
</Window.Resources>
```

...

```
<Expander 
    ExpandDirection="Down" 
    Width="Auto" 
    Padding="4"
    IsExpanded="{Binding XPath=@Expand}"
    >
    <Expander.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Expander">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <!-- 
                You can do a regular Trigger instead of a DataTrigger and not
                have to bother with RelativeSource=Self
                -->
                <Trigger 
                    Property="IsExpanded"
                    Value="True">
                    <!-- stuff -->
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Expander.Style>
    <Expander.Header>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource NameValueConverter}">
            <Binding XPath="@Name" />
            <Binding XPath="@Value" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Expander.Header>
</Expander>
```

---

Here's where `Window.Resources` goes:

```
<Window 
    ...x:Class="..." and other attributes...
    >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:NameConverter x:Key="NameConverter" />

        <!-- other resources -->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!-- The controls that go in the window -->
    </Grid>
</Window
```

Comment: thanks for the response. One question I have is where exactly in the XAML is the Window.Resources supposed to go? Is it supposed to wrap the expander as well? Finally, I am getting the error "The attachable property 'Resources' is not found in type 'Window.' Am I supposed to include a namespace for this?

Comment: @JohnSmitty I can't diagnose XAML I haven't seen, but I've updated my answer. If you still have trouble, please add your new XAML to your answer.

Comment: this seems to work except for one thing.  In the convert you created, I am receiving the error "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Xml.XmlAttribute' to type 'System.String" on the (string)value.  I tried to change this to value.ToString() except that outputs System.Xml.XmlAttribute instead of the actual string. While debugging I can see a parm value in the variable "value" just not sure how to grab it. Any ideas?

Comment: Cast it to XmlAttribute instead of string and take the Value property

Comment: I read through your link of how to implement a multi-value converter and my C# code is fine but how would I go at implementing it in the XAML?

Comment: What's missing from the example? Create it as a resource in the Resources of the same XAML file you're using it in. I'm assuming that's Window. If your Expander is in a UserControl, it would be in UserControl.Resources in the UserControl. Then use it in the binding as I showed in my answer.

Comment: Sorry my question was more of in the syntax of how to do it. I have tried a couple things like  <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding XPath={@Name, @Value}, Converter={StaticResource NameConverter}}" /> but does not seem to work. So my question is do you the syntax in which to create a multi-value converter when defining the Value?

Comment: I gave you the Setter. Are you telling me that you copied and pasted the exact `Setter` XAML that I gave you and it did not work? You can't just make up your own syntax. Or are you telling me that you actually need to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: To start I just needed to pass one Value so I used the exact Setter that you put and it worked. However, I realized I need to pass another parameter to the function with the name so I need to pass multiple parameters. So I was wondering how to pass more than one parameter in the setter.

Comment: I included what type of thing I was looking for in the edit

Comment: that seems to work Thanks for all the help! Appreciate it!